# How can I remove <math></math> multiline sections with Perl?

Tags: perl

How can I remove  multiline sections with Perl?

I have such wiki test code:

```
{|
|-
| colspan="2"|
: <math>
[\underbrace{\color{Red}4,2}_{4 > 2},5,1,7] \rightarrow
[2,\underbrace{\color{OliveGreen}4,5}_{4 < 5},1,7] \rightarrow
[2,4,\underbrace{\color{Red}5,1}_{5 > 1},7] \rightarrow
[2,4,1,\underbrace{\color{OliveGreen}5,7}_{5 < 7}]
</math>
|-
|
: <math>
[\underbrace{\color{OliveGreen}2,4}_{2 < 4},1,5,{\color{Blue}7}] \rightarrow
[2,\underbrace{\color{Red}4,1}_{4 > 1},5,{\color{Blue}7}] \rightarrow
[2,1,\underbrace{\color{OliveGreen}4,5}_{4 < 5},{\color{Blue}7}]
</math>
: <math>
[\underbrace{\color{Red}2,1}_{2 > 1},4,{\color{Blue}5},{\color{Blue}7}] \rightarrow
[1,\underbrace{\color{OliveGreen}2,4}_{2 < 4},{\color{Blue}5},{\color{Blue}7}]
</math>
: <math>
[\underbrace{\color{OliveGreen}1,2}_{1 < 2},{\color{Blue}4},{\color{Blue}5},{\color{Blue}7}]
</math>
|}
```

And I want to remove from this code all  how to do it? I have done such code:

```
cat math-text.txt | perl -e 'while(<>) { s/<math>.+?<\/math>//gs; print $_; }'
```

It is not works but should since documentation explains that `.` will much new lines. How to do it?

Comment: @toolic How to process all lines?

Comment: A hacky way would be to remove all the newlines from the input. Something like `cat math-text.txt | tr -d '\n' | perl ....`

Comment: Can not cut `\n` but it is good idea. Maybe some magic can be used i.e. replace `\n` to `(magic)` then clean code and revert.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a python script which I use to extract all the mathematical formula from wikipedia dumps. Rather than using a multi-line regexp it scans for occurrences of `<math>` `</math>` and uses the position on the line to work out where the actual position on the line is and uses a finite state machine to find the actual equations, basically with two states determined by `inEqn`. It does a few other things like find the title and name space and attributes in the maths tags.

As dumps are in the order of 100MB using a line by line approach may well end up being more efficient than multi-line regexps.

```
import sys
import re

titleRE = re.compile('<title>(.*)</title>')
nsRE = re.compile('<ns>(.*)</ns>')
mathRE = re.compile('&lt;/?math(.*?)&gt;')
pageEndRE = re.compile('</page>')

title =""
attr = ""
ns = -1
inEqn = 0
for line in sys.stdin:
    m = titleRE.search(line)
    if m :
        title = m.group(1)
        expression = ""
        inEqn = 0
    m = nsRE.search(line)
    if m :
        ns = m.group(1)
    start = 0
    pos = 0
    m = mathRE.search(line,pos)
    while m :
        if m.group().startswith('&lt;math'):
            attr = m.group(1)
            start = m.end()
            pos = start
            expression = ""
            inEqn = 1
        if m.group() == '&lt;/math&gt;' :
            end = m.start()
            expression = '    '.join([expression,line[start:end]])
            print title,'\t',attr,'\t',expression.lstrip().replace('&lt;','<').replace('&gt;','>').replace('&amp;','&')
            pos = m.end()
            expression = ""
            start = 0
            inEqn = 0
        m = mathRE.search(line,pos)
    if start > 0 :
        expression = line[start:].rstrip()
    elif inEqn :
        expression = '    '.join([expression,line.rstrip()])
```

Another option might be to consider an xml parser. A SAX or DOM based parser would be able to find the equations. This might be worth considering if you want to do more sophisticated analysis of the wiki-text.

Comment: I am trying to do some word2vec so I plan to use lite parser with Perl but I programming in Python so maybe evolve it to Python.

Comment: If thats http://search.cpan.org/~phred/XML-Parser-Lite-0.721/lib/XML/Parser/Lite.pm You would want to have a CurrentExpression string. In the Start routine, detect if its a math node and clear the CurrentExpression, in the Char add the text to CurrentExpression. When an End tag is encountered you can print the expression. Python has a expat parser so it should be easy to translate from perl.

Comment: It looks little to complex I think. I will try to find simple solution.